# fopen return null and getlasterror return 997(error_io_pending_

Tags: fopen, getlasterror

I use the fopen(filepath, "rb"), but fopen return NULL,

and GetLastError() return 997 (ERROR_IO_PENDING).

I searched about this problem in google, but i can't find anything.

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERROR_IO_PENDING means you can't open the file because it is currently open either for writes or for read in non-shared mode.

Comment: thank you. i found the problem. sometimes, filename is wrong(only filename). but i don't know why get the error code 997 instead of error code 2 (no such a file)